# JavaScript Google DOCS Apps Script - Highlighting the selected row

Tags: javascript, google-docs

could anyone write a simple script to highlighting the selected row.

My monitor displays lines in google sheets very poorly.

I thought that such a script to highlight the poem of my choice would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Comment: Hi Matthev and welcome to SO ! Your answer would be better answered with (preferably) a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or an image of the wanted result and some sample code of things you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from others, I did arrive at a solution - although it's not very snappy still helps tremendously. This script will respond to the active row only if the row number is 6 or greater. It applies the highlight to 7 columns.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R4GPipk9FyucRcKeXcosbKmXxUTGmuaoQDaUoVDVorU/edit?usp=sharing

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
    const s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
    const range = s.getRange('A6:F100');
    const r = s.getActiveCell();
    const maxRows = s.getMaxRows();
    const maxColumns = 7;
    //if (r.getRow() >= range.getRow() && r.getRow() <= range.getLastRow() && r.getColumn() >= range.getColumn() && r.getColumn() <= range.getLastColumn()) {
    if (r.getRow() >= range.getRow() ) {
    
        const range = e.range; 
        s.getRange(1, 1, maxRows, maxColumns).setBackground(null);
        s.getRange(1, range.getColumn(), maxRows, 1);
        s.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, maxColumns).setBackground('Yellow');
    }
}
```